# Creating new record does not register in list without refresh and creates duplicate record

Tags: react-admin

Below is a screenshot of the Redux dev tools. This is a list of records of a particular resource. As you can see, the newly added record has a duplicate with the key `undefined`. It also does not register on the list without a refresh.

[Redux Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaT44.png)

Here is the create component:

```
export const OrgCreate = (props: ReactAdminComponentProps) => {
  const controller = useCreateController(props);
  return (
    <Create {...props} {...controller}>
      <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput source="name" />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  );
};
```

Here is the list component:

```
export const OrgList = (props: ReactAdminComponentProps) => {
  const controller = useListController(props);
  return (
    <List {...props} {...controller} exporter={false} bulkActionButtons={false}>
      <Datagrid rowClick="edit" hasBulkActions={false}>
        <TextField source="name.value" label="Name" />
        <DateField source="createdAt" />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};
```

Here is the create response in the GraphQL provider:

```
createResponse = (data: any) => data.createOrganization.organization;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the lines:

```
const controller = useCreateController(props);
const controller = useListController(props);
```

and further `{...controller}`, it should work.